# Powershell - Remove from string

Tags: json, windows, powershell, scripting

Im extracting a list of IPs from a JSON file using the following syntax

```
$Request = 'https://url-to-json.com/file.json'
$AWSIPs = Invoke-WebRequest $Request | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object prefix -ExpandProperty prefixes -ExcludeProperty ("/.*") | Where-Object -Property "service" -EQ "service_name" | select ip_prefix
foreach ($awsip in $AWSIPs){
echo $awsip
}
```

This returns a list of IPs in this manner:
- 0.0.0.0/00

- 0.0.0.0/00
- 0.0.0.0/00
- 0.0.0.0/00
- 0.0.0.0/00
- 0.0.0.0/00

I need to use this list of IPs, however before I can do so I need to remove the /00 at the end (obviously that's not 00 but it's the subnet mask, which is rarely ever identical).

I'd greatly appreciate help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `-replace`-based solution:

```
$ips =  '0.0.0.0/00',
        '0.0.0.1/01',
        '0.0.0.2/02',
        '0.0.0.3/03',
        '0.0.0.4/04'

$ips -replace '(.*)/.*', '$1'
```

Note how you can use an array directly as the LHS of the `-replace` operation.

The above yields:

```
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.1
0.0.0.2
0.0.0.3
0.0.0.4
```

---

`-split` is an option too, but to avoid additional complexity you need an explicit loop:

```
foreach ($ip in $ips) {
  ($ip -split '/')[0]
}
```

It *is* possible to avoid an explicit loop, but that's probably not worth doing - for reasons of both performance and readability; it does show PowerShell's flexibility, however:

```
($ips -split '/')[(0..($ips.Count-1)).ForEach({ $_ * 2 })]
```